# Unable to see images in rmarkdown table

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I am trying to create a downloadable report from a shiny app. The report shows a table in which there are images.

I am passing the table with the url in the table as a parameter to the report as follows:

```
server <- function(input, output,session) {



  data <- reactive({
    data <- data.frame(RV3$data[,input$Map_EndoscopistIn],
                       RV3$data[,input$Map_FindingsIn],
                       RV3$data[,input$Map_MicroscopicTextIn],
                       RV3$data$url)


    names(data)<-c(input$Map_EndoscopistIn,input$Map_FindingsIn,input$Map_MicroscopicTextIn,"Image")
    if(!is.null(input$EndoscopistChooserIn)){
      data<-data%>%filter(get(input$Map_EndoscopistIn)==input$EndoscopistChooserIn)
    }



    data
  })  


}




output$report <- downloadHandler(
    # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
    filename = "report.doc",
    content = function(file) {
      # Copy the report file to a temporary directory before processing it, in
      # case we don't have write permissions to the current working dir (which
      # can happen when deployed).
      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
      file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)

      browser()
      # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
      params <- list(performanceTable=data()
                     )

      # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
      # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
      # from the code in this app).
      rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                        params = params,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
      )
    }
  )
```

the url column in `data()` contains the following path eg:

```
![](<img src='Images/Images Captured with Proc Data Audit.files/img2527.jpg'>)
```

The report is as follows:

````
---
title: "Dynamic report"
always_allow_html: yes
output:
  word_document:
    fig_caption: true
params:
  performanceTable: NA
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
```

```{r,echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE}

pander(params$performanceTable, justify='left',split.table=Inf,caption="Table 1: Cancer diagnoses")


```
````

The report is in the same folder as the Images folder.

With this I get the following error example:

```
[pandoc warning] Could not find image `img%20src='Images/Images%20Captured%20with%20Proc%20Data%20Audit.files/img2500.jpg'', skipping...
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this a reformatting in pander issue or a paths issue or what? Or could this be that the report root is the tmp directory whereas I am referring to images stored in anoter static directory. If it is the latter, what do I do to get paths relative to the temp directory so I can see the images?

Comment: Why do you need the `img src` tag in the URL column? Not sure what's generating that ... but I think you should get rid of that and try something like `![](Images/Images Captured with Proc Data Audit.files/img2527.jpg)`

Comment: Thanks @daroczig. I have removed the img src and now have as you suggested but I still get teh whitespace replaced with %20. How can I avoid this in pander?

Comment: It's really difficult to figure out what's going on there without a minimal reproducible example :( Can you please try to create one? Eg a small data frame with 2 rows, URL can point to some static image online etc. But I suspect you might need to change the `style` of the `pander` call to `grid` so that markdown get parsed properly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you couldn't locate your image file is because you render your `report.Rmd` from a temp directory where your image doesn't exist:

```
tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd") 
file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
```

The solution is that the image should also be copied to the same temp directory where markdown syntax `![](img.png)` will pick up the file.

As in code change, you should be able to get it working by doing this:

assign a tempDir

```
tempDir <- tempdir()
```

Move Rmd as well as images to tempDir

```
file.copy(c("report.Rmd", "Images/Images Captured with Proc Data 
Audit.files/img2527.jpg"), tempDir, overwrite = TRUE)
```

then render from temp dir

```
rmarkdown::render(file.path(tempDir, 'report.Rmd'), output_file = file,
                        params = params,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
```